# Reduce array of objects into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following array

```
data = [
  { name: 'foo', type: 'fizz', val: 9 },
  { name: 'boo', type: 'buzz', val: 3 },
  { name: 'bar', type: 'fizz', val: 4 },
  { name: 'car', type: 'buzz', val: 7 },
];
```

How do I make it

```
{
    9: 'foo',
    3: 'boo,
    4: 'bar',
    7: 'car'
}
```

in ES6.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `Array#forEach`.

```js
var data = [ { name: 'foo', type: 'fizz', val: 9 }, { name: 'boo', type: 'buzz', val: 3 }, { name: 'bar', type: 'fizz', val: 4 }, { name: 'car', type: 'buzz', val: 7 }, ], 
    res = {};
    data.forEach(v => res[v.val] = v.name);

    console.log(res);
```

Using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var data = [ { name: 'foo', type: 'fizz', val: 9 }, { name: 'boo', type: 'buzz', val: 3 }, { name: 'bar', type: 'fizz', val: 4 }, { name: 'car', type: 'buzz', val: 7 }, ],
    res = data.reduce(function(s,a){
      s[a.val] = a.name;
      return s;
    }, {});
  
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Excuse me, looking forward for some details from the downvoter. If there's something wrong with my answer, tell me and I will improve it.

Comment: Yeah, someone's downvoting our valid answers xD Oh well...

Comment: @Colton Well, officially people are aloud to downvote for any reason at all, including when people give answers to zero-effort questions.

Comment: @Kinduser Thank you for your response!! It's not me who is down voting!! :(

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'foo', type: 'fizz', val: 9 },
  { name: 'boo', type: 'buzz', val: 3 },
  { name: 'bar', type: 'fizz', val: 4 },
  { name: 'car', type: 'buzz', val: 7 },
];

const reduced = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.val] = item.name;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: Instead of a codepen, you can insert a working snippet into your answer (see rightmost button on the toolbar when you edit).

Comment: Oh sweet, I was wondering how people did that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and map arrays with all key/value pairs.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'foo', type: 'fizz', val: 9 }, { name: 'boo', type: 'buzz', val: 3 }, { name: 'bar', type: 'fizz', val: 4 }, { name: 'car', type: 'buzz', val: 7 }],
    object = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ val, name }) => [val, name]));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: @Timo, you need kind of access to the values. by using forEach, you need to declare an array and push the pairs to it. but why?