# Convert Flat JSON Array to JSON Object in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a flat json array that store data like this:

---

```
[
 {
  "prop1": "prop1Data1"
 },
 {
  "prop2": "prop2Data1"
 },
 {
  "prop3.name": "Tom"
 }
]
```

How can I convert this data into simple json object in node js like this:

---

```
{ "prop1": "prop1Data1", "prop2": "prop2Data1", "prop3.name": "Tom" }
```

Comment: There was almost exact question few minutes ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008212/reduce-array-of-objects-into-object/43008248

Comment: Hmm, not exactly. `array[0]`? Please also read the usage description of `json`.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ, not really. there are strings and not objects.

Comment: Ok I got your point

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and use [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for the array.

```js
var array = [{ prop1: "prop1Data1" }, { prop2: "prop2Data1" }, { "prop3.name": "Tom" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(object);
```

ES5 with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and by iterating the keys.

```js
var array = [{ prop1: "prop1Data1" }, { prop2: "prop2Data1" }, { "prop3.name": "Tom" }],
    object = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            r[k] = o[k];
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I've done it was like so, since it is within an array.

```
var original = [{"prop1": "prop1Data1"},{"prop2": "prop2Data1"},{"prop3.name": "Tom"}];

var propStore = {
   prop1 : '',
   prop2 : '',
   prop3 : ''
}
propStore.prop1 = original[0]["prop1"];
propStore.prop2 = original[0]["prop2"];
propStore.prop3 = original[0]["prop3"];

console.log(propStore);
```